# Finding shortest paths with python-IGraph on DAGs with negative weights

Tags: python, shortest-path, igraph, directed-acyclic-graphs, topological-sort

**Task**: Find a shortest path for a DAG (directed acyclic graph) with negative weights using python interface to the igraph library, as a list of edges/vertices in a single-source/single-target setup.

**Tried:** The closest match I found in the documentation is `get_shortest_paths`. However, when tried the function returns:

`igraph._igraph.InternalError: Error at structural_properties.c:5220: Weight vector must be non-negative, Invalid value`

Seems like internally the function tries to apply the Dijkstra's algorithm and fails. In the same time, according to documentation, other shortest path functions (`shortest_paths`, `shortest_paths_dijkstra`) are able to adapt the algorithm to the graph's properties.

**Questions**:

- Is there an alternative function to use in this case?
- Or how to make `get_shortest_paths` chose a correct internal algorithm?
- Or could the algorithm be specified explicitly ([as 
  in the R interface](http://igraph.sourceforge.net/doc/R/shortest.paths.html))

**Related question**:

- Is igraph able to detect that the graph is DAG and use the faster shortest path algorithm on topologically sorted graph?
- Would a custom python code for this be necessarily slower than one of general-purpose internal igraph's algorithms (presumably written in C++)? (|E| is in tens of thousands, |V| is in thousands)

Thanks.

PS. Python 2.7, IGraph 0.6.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`get_shortest_paths` is not able to handle graphs with negative weights because the underlying C library does not have a corresponding `igraph_get_shortest_paths_bellman_ford` function yet. It does have an `igraph_get_shortest_paths_dijkstra`, so the Python interface simply checks whether you have weights and if so, redirects the call to `igraph_get_shortest_paths_dijkstra`, otherwise it simply calls `igraph_get_shortest_paths` (which is the unweighted version in the C layer). In contrast, `shortest_paths` works with negative weights because the C library has a function named `igraph_shortest_paths_bellman_ford` so it calls the Bellman-Ford implementation when at least one of the edge weights is negative.

Unfortunately the only way out seems to be to implement `igraph_get_shortest_paths_bellman_ford` in the C layer and then update the Python interface to handle negative weights appropriately.

Answers to related questions:

- igraph does not check whether the graph is a DAG before running any shortest path related function. Yes, shortest paths can be found faster in a DAG but this use-case is so rare that no one bothered to implement the special case so far.
- Custom code written in pure Python is likely to be slower than a C implementation, but it depends on your problem. If you meant the Bellman-Ford algorithm in particular, a pure Python implementation is *very* likely to be slower, but it may still be usable for the graphs you have. You could try the implementation in [NetworkX](http://networkx.github.io/); as far as I know, NetworkX is pure Python and people still use it for graphs with tens of thousands of nodes and edges.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, already switched from NetworkX to IGraph because the latter is about 1.5 times more memory efficient (need to keep a couple of thousands graphs in memory with rich attributes on each edge). In NetworkX there is no DAG-optimized shortest path routine implemented either. So will stick to a custom python code for DAG's shortest paths again.

Answer (score 0):

I also had a slow R version. It was taking ~20 minutes for 200k edges and 30k vertices, so I broke down and implemented `get.shortest.paths()` in R (but not Python; sorry) and `igraph_get_shortest_paths_bellman_ford()` for graphs with negative edge weights. You can try my fork of R igraph [here](https://github.com/pyrovski/rigraph).

I experienced between 100x and 1000x speedup when switching from my R implementation to C.